# Select2 - load data from server on "open" event and disable ajax search after that

Tags: ajax, yii2, jquery-select2

i'm using select2 and i want this:

1. Empty Select2 is created empty on page load.
2. When user opens it for the first time, ALL data are loading from server.
3. No more ajax calls to server after that - just searh through given result array.

I've done this (yii2 syntax):

```
'pluginOptions' => [
        'minimumInputLength' => 0,
        'ajax' => [
            'url' => "/service/autocomplete",
            'dataType' => 'json',
            'delay' => 250,
            'method' => 'POST',
            'data' => new JsExpression('function(params) { return {mode: "district_metro", s: params.term, service_id: "'.$service_id.'", clinic_type_id: "'.$clinic_type_id.'", cityid: "'.$curcity->id.'", limit:500}; }'),
            'processResults' => new JsExpression($resultsJs),
            'cache' => true
        ],
        'escapeMarkup' => new JsExpression('function (markup) { return markup; }'),
        'templateResult' => new JsExpression('formatRepo'),
        'templateSelection' => new JsExpression('formatRepoSelection'),
    ],
```

I've set minimumInputLength to zero - so, when user is opening the select2, ALL resulats are actually loaded from server it's ok.

But when user is trying to type something, another ajax call is fired, but i d't need this ajax calls cause all the data is loaded already.

My question is: is there any way to disable ajax search after first one?

Sry for bad english.

Comment: I don't know yii2, but why not preload the objects in an ajax call outside of select2, and then populate it using the `data` option instead of ajax?

Comment: Why you are calling ajax. when page load get all data.

Comment: I want to load data only when user click on select (there are a lot of data and i d't want to load it every page load).